# Scale the height of a UITableViewCell based on the table's readable width

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell`, which contains a subview that has a 4:3 aspect ratio and should scale to the readable width of the table.  I build it programmatically like this:

```
class MapCell: UITableViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate {
    private let mapView = MKMapView()

    init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(self.mapView)
        self.mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mapView, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mapView, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mapView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.mapView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0)
        ])
        self.mapView.delegate = self
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And in the view controller I set `self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = true`.  This almost works, but I can't get the height of the cell to fit the subview properly.  I want to do something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.getCellType(for: indexPath) == .mapCell {
        return tableView.readableWidth * 0.75
    } else {
        return 44
    }
}
```

Obviously that property doesn't exist, but I can't find one that provides the value I need - all of the "width" and "size" properties I checked are either too large or 0.  Is there any way to do this?

[Here is an example of the full width vs the width I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOPwo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take the size of the screen or tableView.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.getCellType(for: indexPath) == .mapCell {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75
    } else {
        return 44
    }
}
```

Could you attach images to understand what a cell should be?

Comment: No, I don't want the full width of the table, just the part that's actually displaying content.  I added an image to show what I mean.